# QGIS line style with alternating dashes - and x

Tags: qgis, style, line

I found the latest QGIS has a great tool to create complex styles, however looks like one small but very useful thing is missing, or I can't find it.
I'm trying to create a line style something like "- x - x -". I can do it in various ways, but none of them gives right results. The problem is that I need to set starting point (shift) either for "-" or "x", so to draw it not from 0. If I set X coordinate shift for the marker it works ok, except line bends, where marker can go outside the line (vertex).

**QGIS style:**

[image: QGIS style]

**ArcMap style:**

[image: ArcMap style]

Is there is something to do with it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can adjust the phase of your dash pattern by inserting a row in the Dash space pattern editor with a Dash of 0 length and a Space of half the length you want between your dashes. In the second row, you set the full Dash length, and half the desired Space length again.

For example, if you set the Marker line to use an interval of 10, you could set your dash pattern to 0, 2.5, 5, 2.5 like in the following screenshot:

[image]

Resulting in this:

[image]

Comment: That's an elegant solution which will be useful to me too. I tried to make the dashed line using symbols, but of course these won't "bend". Thanks. N.

Comment: Thank you Jake. It really solves the problem. I will do futher experiments with other styles as well.